# How to import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker' into Aurelia project

Tags: javascript, aurelia, systemjs, jspm, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to add 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker' into an Aurelia with typescript project and call `this.birthDateDatePicker.datetimepicker();` in the "attached" method from the Aurelia life-cycle.

I added:

```
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import {datepicker} from 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

and there was no error,
but when I try to inject like this `@inject(HttpClient, json, datepicker)` I get the following error:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)

I'm not sure the two libraries are loaded because I cannot find them in the sources on the browser debugger.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

[image with more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRZFj.gif)

The error on that line is

> "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError:
>   this.birthDateDatePicker.datetimepicker is not a function"

SOLUTION:

I've added the following imports:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

and manually added in the config.js the fallowing map:

```
"jquery":"github:components/jquery@2.2.0",
```

Comment/Question: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to manually add it there but I could not use it from bootstrap like in the skeleton application and I saw it was present in the global dependencies of the package.json file and found it under "jspm_packages/github/components".

Is this a correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: no, it is not good idea, because config.js is generated file and it will be overwritten when installing project from scratch, the best way is to install `jquery` package as primary package, because now you have it as a dependency. `jspm install jquery=github:components/jquery`

Comment: Thanks for the install part, I've tried to install jquery before and got an "extraneous" error when doing so, that's why I manually updated it in the end.
The config.js is generated as expected now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use aurelia-skeleton as boilerplate

```
import $ from 'bootstrap';
```

EDITED:
Also use `import 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';` to add datetimepicker as jquery module to globals

Comment: I've added a image with more details of my configuration. (as much as I could with a print screen)
I've tried these configurations:
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';
or
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';
and the only one that didn't give an error on loading was 
'import $ from 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';'

Comment: note, `import $ from 'bootstrap';` BOOTSTRAP, not jquery

Comment: also I suggest you need $(this.birthDateDatePicker).datetimepicker(), if `birthDateDatePicker` is a `ref`in template

Answer (score 3):

aha, it wasn't clear to me what you were doing when we were chatting in the gitter.  I think I see the issue now...

The bootstrap-datetimepicker is a jQuery plugin, loading the module installs the plugin's functionality in jquery.  It may not export anything.  If it does export something, it should be the jquery object.

Try one of these:

```js
import $ from 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

In any of these cases, there's no need to involve dependency injection (`@inject` etc).  Use the `$` variable directly.

Comment: I've added a image with more details of my configuration (as much as I could with a print screen) I've tried these configurations: import $ from 'jquery'; import 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker'; or import $ from 'jquery'; import 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker'; and the only one that didn't give an error on loading was 'import $ from 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';'

Comment: I imported the bootstrap-datetimepicker but I am missing css. I dont see the calendar. Any ideas?